# How to get content to display on Heroku from a Ruby app built with Nesta CMS?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, nestacms

I added the demo files and ran the app just fine locally

[image: site running locally]

But I ran into problems when i deployed to heroku, the content was not showing
[image: deployed to heroku]
I read through the documentation on the official site for nesta at 
http://nestacms.com/docs/deployment/heroku
But they pretty much just make a comment rather than offering instruction

> Make sure that you fill in config/config.yml properly (the most important thing is to ensure that caching is off, as we can’t write to Heroku’s file system).

Well I followed their documentation elsewhere 
http://nestacms.com/docs/config

And then made changes to my `config.yml` file. Most relevant changes below

```
title: "Practice Nesta Site"
subtitle: "Nesta is pretty cool"

author:
  name: Juan Gallardo
  uri: nestademo1.herokuapp.com
  email: jgallardo720@gmail.com

# cache
#     Set it to true if you'd like Nesta to cache your pages in ./public.
#     Useful if you're deploying Nesta with a proxy server such as Nginx,
#     but not in the least bit helpful if your pages are dynamic, or you're
#     deploying Nesta to Heroku.
#
cache: false

# content
#     The root directory where nesta will look for your article files.
#     Should contain "pages" and "attachments" subdirectories that contain
#     your actual content and the (optional) menu.txt file that links to your
#     main category pages.
#
content: content

# Overriding "cache" and "content" in production is recommended if you're
# deploying Nesta to your own server (but see the deployment documentation
# on the Nesta site). Setting google_analytics_code in production is
# recommended regardless of how you're deploying (if you have a GA account!).
#
# Don't forget to uncomment the "production:" line too...

production:
  cache: false    
  content: /var/apps/nesta/shared/content
#  google_analytics_code: "UA-???????-?"

read_more: See full page
```

Full file at this gist 
https://gist.github.com/JGallardo/6195651

I ran heroku logs
`jgallardo:demo-site juan.gallardo$ heroku logs
2013-08-09T17:22:21+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-09T17:23:35.001505+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-08-09T17:23:35.026933+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 953af2e by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-08-09T17:23:35.046866+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-08-09T17:23:35.085708+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 953af2e by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-08-09T17:23:35+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-09T17:23:39.139164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command`bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 4751
`2013-08-09T17:23:42.686255+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-09 17:23:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-08-09T17:23:42.686255+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-09 17:23:42] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
2013-08-09T17:23:42.686477+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-09 17:23:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=4751
2013-08-09T17:23:43.030091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-09T17:36:17.229501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=nestademo1.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=51ms status=404 bytes=1570
2013-08-09T17:36:17.658553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/css/master.css host=nestademo1.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=129ms status=200 bytes=5548`

Comment: Don't link to your config.yml, include the important information in your question. If the link breaks your question will not have the necessary information and will be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
content: /var/apps/nesta/shared/content
```

Change it to this:

```
content: content
```

And make sure that your content is checked into the code repo. You've probably found this page already, right? http://nestacms.com/docs/deployment/heroku

Comment: Yes, I saw that page and cited it in the question. But the instructions did not mention what you said above.